# Provide value from node to angular universal

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

We have an Angular Universal app where we need to pass a value from node.js to angular when running server-side. We have solved this by using the following code in server.ts:

```
const theValue: TheType = nodeLogicToRetrieveValue();

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  let engine = ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      { provide: 'theKey', useFactory: () => theValue, deps: [] }
    ]
  });
  engine(_, <any>options, callback)
});
```

In the component we resolve this object with the following code:

```
if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
  this.theValue = this.injector.get('theKey');
}
```

This works fine, however linting gives the following warning:

> get is deprecated: from v4.0.0 use Type<T> or InjectionToken<T>

We try to change this to so that we use InjectionToken (`new InjectionToken<TheType>('theKey')`) or the type instead of the string but this won't work:

> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppServerModule)[TheType]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TheType]: 
>        NullInjectorError: No provider for TheType!

Is it only possible to pass values from node to angular through string tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by providing an InjectionToken with the string (used as key) as value. The InjectionToken can be typed to `TheType`, and lint will not give the warning.

Create an InjectionToken in a separate file to avoid a circular dependency.

**tokens.ts**

```
export const TOKEN = new InjectionToken<TheType>('theKey');
```

Provide the InjectionToken in appServerModule.

**app.server.module.ts**

```
providers: [
    ....
    { provide: TOKEN, useValue: 'theKey', deps: [] }
]
```

Inject the token and decorate it with `@Optional()`, since the browser will also try to inject the token (and fail because lack of provider). The value passed from node is only relevant to the server and there's no need to provide the InjectionToken for `appModule`.

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(@Optional() @Inject(TOKEN) private token: InjectionToken<TheType>, ...){
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
       this.theValue = this.injector.get(this.token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to tweak Emil's answer to get it to work (I'm using angular 10).

#### Define the token:

```js
export const CLIENT_ID = new InjectionToken<string>('client-id');
```

#### Provide the value from the server:

```js
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
    providers: [
      {
        provide: CLIENT_ID,
        useValue: 'MyClientId',
      },
    ],
  }) as any);
```

#### Inject the value in the client:

```js
constructor(@Optional() @Inject(CLIENT_ID) private clientId: string){
  console.log(this.clientId);
}
```